# Existence of holomorphic function on unit disk satifying a certain condition

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to find all the holomorphic functions on the unit disk satisfying the condition $f(\frac{1}{n^2+1}) = 0 $ $\forall $ $ n \in \mathbb N$.
I am not quite sure as to which theorem I should use. My guess is that I apply the Identity theorem and thus the only function possible is $f(z) = 0$.

Comment: you're on the right track

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. If such a function existed, it would be continuous and therefore$$f(0)=f\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n^2+1}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f\left(\frac1{n^2+1}\right)=0.$$So, the set of zeros of $f$ contains$$\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac1{n^2+1}\,\middle|\,n\in\Bbb N\right\}$$and therefore it has an accumulation point (which is $0$). So, by the identity theorem, $f$ is the null function.